# GAE deployment (standard F1) outperforming (standard F2) with identical source?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, next.js

I have 2 GCP projects "dev", and "prod" for a simple NextJS app. I am deploying to App Engine with the following configurations:

### app.dev.yaml

```
runtime: nodejs16
instance_class: F1
handlers:
  - url: /.*
    secure: always
    script: auto
  - url: /icons
    static_dir: /public/icons
```

### app.prod.yaml

```
runtime: nodejs16
instance_class: F2
handlers:
  - url: /.*
    secure: always
    script: auto
  - url: /icons
    static_dir: /public/icons
```

### next.config.js

```
const nextConfig = {
  experimental: {
    externalDir: true
  },
  reactStrictMode: true,
  images: {
    domains: ["ik.imagekit.io"]
  },
  distDir: "build"
};

module.exports = nextConfig;
```

### package.json (scripts)

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start -p 8080",
    "deploy:dev": "npm run build && gcloud app deploy --quiet --project=<dev-project> --appyaml=app.dev.yaml",
    "deploy:prod": "npm run build && gcloud app deploy --quiet --project=<prod-project> --appyaml=app.prod.yaml",
    "lint": "next lint --fix",
    "format": "prettier --write './**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx,css,md,json}' --config ./.prettierrc"
  },
```

My dev environment (F1 instance) performs substantially better than my prod environment (F2). Way faster cold boots and image loading. The dev instance was able to quickly render a 2MB hero jpg that consistently caused a memory fault on the prod instance. I've played around with different instance classes for prod (and eventually tinified the jpg), but nothing seems to perform as well as my dev standard environments F1.  I have double and triple checked the instance classes in the GCP console for each project.  At this point, I do not want to go to flex.  I need to understand what is driving the inconsistency between the projects to be able to accurately gauge the appropriate GAE deployment for production.

Comment: No, these are both my question.

Comment: Could you please edit your question and share the code you're using to have a [minimal code that reproduces the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?